Show that $\int_0^{\pi/3}\arccos^2(2\sin^2 x-\cos x)\mathrm dx=\frac{19\pi^3}{135}$

Show that $$\int_0^{\pi/3}\arccos^2(2\sin^2 x-\cos x)\mathrm dx=\frac{19\pi^3}{135}$$

Wolfram strongly suggests that it's true.
Here is the graph of $y=\arccos^2(2\sin^2 x-\cos x)$.

Context
I stumbled upon this when I was trying to answer a similar question: Show that $\int_0^{\pi/3}\arccos(2\sin^2 x-\cos x)\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi^2}{5}$.
My attempt
Using the first three substitutions from the answer to the similar question, I got:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}\arccos^2(2\sin^2 x-\cos x)\mathrm dx$$
$$\overset{\large\tan\frac{x}{2}\to x}=2\int_0^\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\frac{\arccos^2\left(\frac{-1+8x^2+x^4}{(1+x^2)^2}\right)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx$$
$$=8\int_0^\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\frac{\arctan^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{1-3x^2}{5+x^2}}\right)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx$$
$$\overset{\large\frac{1}{x}\to\sqrt x}=4\int_3^\infty\frac{\arctan^2\left(\sqrt x\sqrt{\frac{x-3}{5x+1}}\right)}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)}\mathrm dx$$
$$\overset{\large \frac{x-3}{5x+1}\to x}=16\int_0^\frac{1}{5} \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-5x)} \frac{\arctan^2\left(\sqrt x\sqrt{\frac{3+x}{1-5x}}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{3+x}{1-5x}}}\mathrm dx$$
But this doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Why the bounty ? 843 views in 7 days , 2 answers with one accept ?

@mick When I started the bounty, there were no answers. I started the bounty to draw more attention to the question.

oh i see. well done ! :)

Computing the integral
We can start by rewriting the integral in terms of its inverse, similarly as seen in this answer.
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\arccos^2(2\sin^2 x-\cos x) dx \overset{x \to \pi-x}= \int_{\frac{2\pi}{3}}^\pi\arccos^2(2\sin^2 x+\cos x) dx$$
$$\small =\pi^3-\int_0^{\pi^2} \arccos\left(\frac14-\frac14 \sqrt{17-8\cos \sqrt{y}}\right)dy\overset{y\to y^2}=\pi^3-2\int_0^{\pi} y\arccos\left(\frac14-\frac14 \sqrt{17-8\cos y}\right)dy$$
Next, we should notice that the $\arccos$ argument is the "$-$" solution of a quadratic equation with $b=-\frac12$ and $c=\frac{\cos y}{2}-1$ in $y_{\pm}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}$. Using Vieta's relations we can easily simplify $\arccos y_-\pm\arccos y_+=\arccos\left(y_-y_+\mp\sqrt{(1+y_-y_+)^2-(y_-+y_+)^2}\, \right)$, and therefore, it makes sense to also consider the "$+$" solution like this:
$$\mathcal J_{\pm}=\int_0^\pi y\arccos\left(\frac14\pm\frac14 \sqrt{17-8\cos y}\right)dy$$
Here it should be noted that the "$+$" solution is a purely imaginary number, as the $\arccos$ argument is outside the $(-1,1)$ range, thus we can subtract it from the original integral and directly take the real part.
$$\Rightarrow I= \pi^3-2 \mathcal J_{-}=\pi^3-2\Re\left(\mathcal J_{-}-\mathcal J_{+}\right)= \pi^3-2\Re \int_0^\pi y \arccos\left(-1+\frac12e^{iy}\right)dy$$
$$=4\Re \int_0^\pi y\arcsin\left(\frac12 e^{iy/2}\right)dy=2\Re\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{2^{4n} (n!)^2(2n+1)} \int_0^\pi y e^{iy(n+1/2)}dy$$
$$=4\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{4n} (n!)^2 (2n+1)^2}-8 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{2^{4n} (n!)^2 (2n+1)^3}$$
$$=8\pi\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}{y}dy+16 \int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\ln y}{y}dy$$
$$=\frac{2\pi^3}{5} - \frac{7\pi^3}{27}=\boxed{\frac{19\pi^3}{135}}$$
Above we used the power series of the $\arcsin$ function (twice) as well as the one for $\operatorname{arcsinh}$. Also, the first integral can be found here and the second one here (after integrating it by parts).

Generalization
It might be worth to mention that we can further attempt to generalize the integral as:
$$I(k)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3} \arccos^k\left(2\sin^2 x- \cos x \right) dx=2k\Re \int_0^\pi y^{k-1}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}2 e^{iy/2}\right)dy$$
$$=2k\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{2^{4n} (n!)^2(2n+1)} \Re\left(\frac{1}{i^{k-1}}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dn^{k-1}}\frac{i+e^{in\pi}}{2n+1}\right)$$
For example, with $k=3$ we'll obtain:
$$\small I(3)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3} \arccos^3\left(2\sin^2 x- \cos x \right) dx=6\pi^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{4n} (n!)^2(2n+1)^2}-48\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{4n} (n!)^2(2n+1)^4}$$
$$\small =12\pi^2\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}{y}dy-48 \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\ln^2 y}{y}dy=\frac{3\pi^4}{5}-48_5F_4\left(\begin{array}{c}\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12\\ \tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|-\tfrac14\right)$$
Above there's a huge chance that the last hypergeometric function can be simplified, as we have the closed form for a similar one here:
$$\small _5F_4\left(\begin{array}{c}\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12\\ \tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|\color{red}{\tfrac14}\right)  = \frac{\pi}{12}\zeta(3)+\frac{27}{32}\operatorname{Cl}_4\big(\tfrac23\pi\big)$$
Update: Thanks to KStar's efforts, we can indeed obtain a closed form for $I(3)$.
$$I(3)=\boxed{\frac{4\pi^4}{15}-24\zeta(3)\ln(\varphi)+2\pi^2\ln(\varphi)^2-5\ln(\varphi)^4-15\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{\varphi^2}\right)}$$
However, starting from $I(4)$ it seems that the integrals are no longer reducible in closed form, without introducing new special functions.
$$\small I(4)=8\pi^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2n)!}{2^{4n} (n!)^2(2n+1)^2} - 192\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2n)!}{2^{4n} (n!)^2(2n+1)^4} + 384\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{2^{4n} (n!)^2(2n+1)^5}$$
$$\small = 16\pi^3 \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}{y} dy - 192\pi \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \ln^2 y}{y}dy - 128 \int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \ln^3 y}{y}dy $$
$$\small =\boxed{\frac{179}{243}\pi^5-96\pi \ln(\varphi)\zeta(3)+8\pi^3\ln^2(\varphi)-20\pi \ln^4(\varphi)-60\pi\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{\varphi^2}\right)-96\operatorname{Gl}_{4,1}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}$$
Above we introduced the multiple Glaisher function, as seen in $2$ and $5.1$ from this article. In our particular case there is $\operatorname{Gl}_{4,1}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{n-1}}{n^4}\sin\frac{n\pi}{3}$.

Incredible work! (+1)

You really are the king of Ahmed-type integrals. (+1)

This is brilliant

Mind blowing solution!!!(+1)

Thank you all for the nice words!

A truly beautiful result: $$3\cdot {}_5F_4\left(\begin{array}{c}\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12\ \tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|-\tfrac14\right)=\frac{\pi^4}{48}+\frac{3\zeta(3)}{2}\log(\varphi)-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\log(\varphi)^2+\frac{5}{16}\log(\varphi)^4+\frac{15}{16}\mathrm{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{\varphi^2}\right),$$ where $\varphi :=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio. I would be more than happy to prove this for you if interested!

One can in fact keep going. Similarly, $$24{}6F_5\left(\begin{array}{c}\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12\ \tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|-\tfrac14\right)=\frac{1}{16}\int{0}^{\varphi}\frac{\log\left(\frac{1+x}{x^2}\right)^4}{1+x},\mathrm{d}x.$$ I have yet to evaluate this integral, however.

@KStar very impressive! It would definitely be of great interest to see an approach of deriving that closed form, I'm sure your approach could serve as a reference for many other similar integrals in future.

This is in specific response to the generalization mentioned in Zacky's (incredible) answer (I lack the necessary reputation to comment.)
Evaluating $$S_-=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2n+1)^4\,(-4)^n\,n!}$$
should eventually give a very similar closed form for
$$_5F_4\left(\begin{array}{c}\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12\\ \tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|-\tfrac14\right)$$ as the one in that original question, although not without some effort.
I will be able to look at this more in a few days, but as of now I do not have the time, so I am putting this out here in case anyone wishes to try it themselves.
If someone wishes to make this a comment, somehow, I would be thankful.

This is just loose, actually there should some simpler sums that will result in the necessary function much easier... I just cannot think of one directly.

Hey just to let you know, I have evaluated this series- see my comment on Zacky's answer above!
